# d3 drawing svg elements on canvas

Tags: d3.js, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw something on top of a canvas that's constantly scrolling up.  The canvas is created as a foreign object

```
this.svg = d3.select(this.root.nativeElement).append("svg")

let foreigner = this.svg.append("foreignObject")
  .attrs({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: `${this.width}`,
    height: `${this.height}`
  })
```

I draw some lines on it:

```
let g = this.svg.append("g")
g.append("line").attrs({
  x1: 100,
  y1: 0,
  x2: 100,
  y2: this.height-1,
  stroke: "orange"
})
```

and all is well until it starts scrolling up.  The scrolling is a timer that uses drawImage to draw the image so many pixels up, then paint some new stuff at the bottom.  For a test I just threw something together to generate random black blocks.

```
let step = 2

ctx.drawImage(ctx.canvas,
  0, step,
  this.width, this.height - step,
  0, 0,
  this.width, this.height - step)

let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.width)
ctx.fillStyle = "black"
ctx.fillRect(x - step, this.height - step, 5, step)
```

The scrolling up part works.  But what happens is that when it scrolls enough my orange lines disappear.  They're still in the rendered SVG and they are still later in the file (higher z order) than the canvas, but they're no longer visible.

What makes it do this?  Is the canvas inside the foreign object not really treated the same as built-in svg objects?

Comment: This might be a chrome problem because this works as I expected (honoring the layers) in firefox.  what troubles me is that when I see something like this it's usually because I did something not compliant with the spec.  In the above for example I realized I didn't explicitly set the width and height.  I have fixed that, but on chrome 73.0.3683.86 at least it still doesn't obey the layering.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you could provide an executable demo, prefer a Stack Snippet.